# Generate a new Ecore metamodel based on another one in Java

Tags: java, transformation, emf, metamodel, ecore

I am a beginner in Eclipse EMF.
I have created an Ecore metamodel which I want to transform into a new Ecore metamodel in Java that takes into account some characteristics of the first metamodel. I have searched the web but the exlpanations I've found were not clear to me.

How can I get access to the first metamodel from a Java app and how can I generate a new metamodel with the corresponding .ecore and .genmodel files?

Is such a task even possible?

Thanks!

Comment: why do you want to generate a new model? have you thought about changing it with edapt and creating a new release?

Answer (score 0):

There is EMF Epsilon language framework which you can use for model transformations. It is written in Java and can be used in java applications. [Here is an example](https://www.eclipse.org/epsilon/examples/index.php?example=org.eclipse.epsilon.examples.standalone).

Answer (score 0):

You can access in this way :

```
ResourceSet rs = new ResourceSetImpl();
Resource resource = rs.getResource(URI.createFileURI(metamodelStringURI), true);
```